# how to add/remove data to state depending on if the checkbox was checked and then unchecked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to get the values from checkboxes, ids, so that I can do some logic and store them on a db. What I am trying to do is something like a week calendar, and if you click on one, it means you selected that day, for example `id: 1 = Sun`, but if I click it again I don't want it to duplicate the id, I rather want it to not be selected meaning, remove it. This is what I have done, I even tried using sets but it is not working(the set adds and removes stuff, but the issue is clearly on the `(prev) => [...]`) that is what I think it is what i am doing wrong so I think I just need some recommendation on how to do it.

```
const [dayId, setDayId] = useState([]);

{days.map((day, idx) => (
                <input onChange={(e) => {
                    let checked = e.target.value;
                    const values = new Set();
                    setDays(
                        days.map(data => {
                            if (data.id === day.id) {
                                let value = e.target.value;
                                data.id = value;
                                if(data.select === false) {
                                    data.select = true;
                                }
                                else {
                                    data.select = false;
                                }
                            }
                            return data;
                        })
                    );
                    if(values.has(checked)) {
                        values.delete(checked);
                    }
                    if(e.target.checked === true) {
                        values.add(checked);
                    }
                    if(e.target.value === false) {
                        values.delete(checked);
                    }
                    setDayId(prev => {
                        return [...prev, ...values]
                    })
                    console.log("CHECKING CHECKED VALUE", e.target.checked);
                    console.log("WHAT IS THE SET VALUE", values)
                }} key={idx} name={day?.name} type="checkbox" value={day?.id} checked={day.select}  />
            ))}
```

In summary, I want that array to add remove values depending if they were checked and then unchecked, the `set` actually does it, but the values are not kept so that is why I did this, `setDayId(prev => {return [...prev, ...values]})`, but that right there keeps the values and never removes them and even duplicates them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So basically you want to add the id if `checked` is true, and remove the id if `checked` is false, from the `dayId` state?

Comment: @DrewReese yes that is what I want to do. But it just keeps all the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question you basically want to add the id if `checked` is true, and remove the id if `checked` is false, from the `dayId` state. In `setDayId` check the `checked` value and if true then shallow copy the `dayId` state and append the new id (`value`), otherwise remove it from the `dayId` array using a `.filter` function.

```
{days.map((day, idx) => (
  <input
    onChange={(e) => {
      const { checked, value } = e.target;

      setDays(
        days => days.map(data => {
          if (data.id === day.id) {
            return {
              ...data,
              id: value,
              select: !data.select,
            };
          }
          return data;
        })
      );
    
      setDayId(prev => {
        return checked
          ? [...prev, value]                  // add if checked
          : prev.filter(val => val !== value) // remove if not checked
      });

      console.log("CHECKING CHECKED VALUE", e.target.checked);
      console.log("WHAT IS THE SET VALUE", values)
    }}
    key={idx}
    name={day?.name}
    type="checkbox"
    value={day?.id}
    checked={day.select}
  />
))}
```